# Require valid user in Apache 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, basic-authentication

I have the following config in my `.htaccess` file, which is working in Apache 2.2, but not in 2.4:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/admin require_auth=true

AuthUserFile /var/www/site.htpasswd
AuthName "Admin Access"
AuthType Basic

Require all denied
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

How do I convert this to work in Apache 2.4? Basically, if the URI starts with `/admin`, then they should be asked for the password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put this `.htaccess` file in the folder you want to protect:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/site/.htpasswd
AuthName "Admin Access"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

From https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html

> For example, if you wish to protect the directory /usr/local/apache/htdocs/secret, you can use the following directives, either placed in the file /usr/local/apache/htdocs/secret/.htaccess, or placed in httpd.conf inside a <Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/secret"> section.

But with the new `If` directive we could do it from the root directory as well:

```
<If "'%{REQUEST_URI}' =~ m#/?admin(/.*)?#">
    AuthUserFile /var/www/site/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Admin Access"
    AuthType Basic
    require valid-user
</If>
```

I tested this positive on a Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS Server with Apache 2.4.27.

Comment: This does not allow me to apply it based on the URL as per my current config.

Comment: Than just use the If Directive as added above

Answer (score 3):

You must use the full path to your .htpasswd file.

I will show you the easiest way to get this path.

Create a .php file in the same folder, containing the following code :

```
<?php
echo dirname(__FILE__) . '/.htpasswd';
?>
```

Then access it via your browser and it should display the full path you'll need to put in your .htaccess file.